# how to get input value and set this value in other input

Tags: javascript

I need pass and set the value of input id="a" to input id="b" when keyup. Any idea??

```
<input id="a" name="a" value="" type="text">
<input id="b" name="b" value="" type="text">

var a = document.getElemntById('a').value
var b = document.getElementById('b').value = $a
```

Comment: What have you tried? What's `$a`? You seem to want to use the keyup event, so have you written any code to try it?

Comment: Yes I try to use keyup event the next way: IDa.addEventListener('keyup')

Comment: Basically, I need to know how I assign the value of a variable to an Id Element, Ex: document.getElementById ('b'). Value = variable 'a' when a.addEventListener('keyup')

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this..

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

   Name: <input type="text" id="myText" >
   2nd Name : <input type="text" id="myText2" >
   <p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
      <script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText2").value = document.getElementById("myText").value;
   }
     </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```